# How to start jenkins server on <myaddress>:8080/jenkins instead of <myaddress>:8080

Tags: jenkins, routes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am running Jenkins server on AWS EC2.

I tried changing Jenkins URL to myaddress:8080/jenkins in Manage Jenkins->Configure System Section.

Also tried editing JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS to 0.0.0.0/jenkins/ and JENKINS_PREFIX to /jenkins in Jenkins.Service File in lib/systemd/system.

But still server is running on myaddress:8080 instead of myaddress:8080/jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jenkins Initial Settings](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/)

`--prefix=$PREFIX`

> Runs Jenkins to include the $PREFIX at the end of the URL. For example, set `--prefix=/jenkins` to make Jenkins accessible at `http://myServer:8080/jenkins`